# How to allow "active mode" FTP connections in Windows

Tags: windows-7, ftp

I have been using a script forever that uses the windows command line FTP to upload files to a third-party server. (I'm using Windows 7.) Third party recently got a new server and now I can still connect but I can't issue any commands without the connection hanging. I can't even do `ls` much less a `put`. It hangs on "Opening data connection for...." After much research I've narrowed it down to their new server not being configured to allow "active mode" FTP connections. I can't configure their server for them, and at this point I'm not sure how competent the server manager is. So I want to know what steps I can tell them to do to configure the server to allow "active mode" FTP connections. I assume their using a windows 7 machine. What do I need to tell them?

Comment: Please move your question to [su] or [sf]. It's [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Follow this:

Control Panel -> Internet Options -> Advanced tab

Scroll down until you find a checkbox labeled "Use Passive FTP".

Uncheck it.